# Как вывести окно с выбором языка и входом в аккаунт фейсбука только при первом запуске приложения?

Tags: facebook, настройка

Доброе время суток!

Я пишу приложение и мне необходимо следующее:
при первом старте приложения самое первое что видит пользователь после окна загрузки - это окно выбора языка и предложения войти через свой аккаунт в фейсбук.

Как это можно реализовать, чтобы в последующие запуски приложения это окно уже не появлялось.

Я новичок, не могу пока дотумкать, практики не хватает, помогите дрУги! )

Comment: Написали бы на чем пишете приложение-то, а то в разных системах  это по разному реализуется

Comment: Да вопрос был по objective-c,
реализовал через использование NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если эти данные отсутствуют то не говорит ли это о том, что это первый запуск?
Выдавайте окна если данных нет, и все.